# unreachable host in iOS 6.1.3 since iPhone 3GS

Tags: ios, iphone-3gs

Some one knows why since iPhone 3GS the web services is unreachable, but since iPad and XCode Simulator works fine.

Could be a specific configuration of IIS where is the web services (WCF web service)

Anyone can help me?